# Why do my point lights have red X's on them in the Unreal editor?

Tags: lighting, unreal-4

I've noticed through the first two tutorials I've done that Point Lights begin entering the viewport with red x's on them. When I build those don't turn on. It seems to be implying some limit to the number of Point Lights in a given space. Is that space the lightmass importance volume, or a given scene? I checked the Point Light tutorial explanation to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

[You can only have 4 overlapping point lights](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/LightingTroubleshootingGuide#Why_is_there_a_red_.E2.80.9CX.E2.80.9D_over_my_light.3F). I guess your radii must overlap. You can read more about standard issues with lights in the  [lighting troubleshooting guide](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/LightingTroubleshootingGuide).